# $.ajax with JSON/and javascript OR $.load a page in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I cannot find the answer of the following question : in a full Ajax Website, what is better ?

-1- use $.ajax to load a PHP file that returns you a JSON answer, and write it on the page with javascript

OR

-2- use the easier way to load a PHP file that asks the server and write the answer immediatly in HTML.

For small applications, the -1- is obviously better, but when you have to write down on the page sth like 70 photos and 10 000 characters with a lot of different styles, it becomes very heavy for the navigator isn't it ? I bet that for the server the -1- is anyway still the best...

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matter of server-side performance, especially for pages with lot of requests, I would suggest to use the first approach and save bandwidth (you can use [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for this purpose) .

Furthermore if you serve a `JSON` instead of the whole markup, you can better separate the data (and the logic behind) from the presentation, so your site is more mantainable and may scale well.

You could ask `JSON` data from your server and then you could inject the received data with some kind of client-side templating system, like `mustache` or `handlebars`

Comment: I mustache you a question! You can also have HTML returning from `$.ajax`, no? Then what's the exclusive purpose of `$.load`?

Comment: returning HTML from $.ajax is possible but JSON is much faster, so it's worse that -1- and -2- ;)

Answer (score 0):

what i usually do is create the view in a serverside language ( cq php ) than present the page through a url or load it in through jQuery $.load

this just loads a piece of html in, even with specific selector elements in the source. This way you are quite dynamic and you dont have to parse you html to json and back.

Good luck!

And for you question about a page with massive content, take a look at some infinite scrolling, or loading content when the items are in the viewport with a nice fade-in effect or so? That way you limit the no of requests to the server by allot

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need. If it is indeed `full Ajax Website` then obviously (1) is better.

Downside of (1) is that if you have a lot of ajax request, you can slow down the page, because browser will only make a limited number of requests at a time, i.e. it will not load 20 requests at once, it will load them 3 by 3 or 5 by 5. 
Upside is, obviously, that page loads much faster initially without the content as content is later displayed. This also allows you have dynamic paging (without reload of the page), search, etc.

Number (2) is better in a way that when the page finishes loading, it finished loading, all the content is there, you do not have to wait additionally for ajax requests to finish. Downside is obviously that you will have to wait longer for initial download to finish since you are sending all data at once.

It really depends on what you need, but usually combination of the (1) and (2) is a win. You need to decide where to use (1) and where to use (2). For example, you could use (2) for initial page load (to display the first page of the result) and then page through subsequent pages using (1).

Also, if you are only using ajax to load image list, you are not gaining much by ajax, since `<img>` tags add little overhead to initial download of the page, images load afterwards anyway, so you do not save much by using ajax.

JSON is definitely a way to go for ajax calls since it is supported in both java and php, and does not have too much overhead for data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Today most are on high speed internet. So it doesn't matter on how many bytes u save comparing json to html

Also, most are on high end cpu or mobile devices. As such a common web solution doesn't factor cpu cycles in client or server

Having json, encourages service oriented architecture and client can wish which data to display. More CPU consumed on client machine

Having HTML, you can target just 1client. Less CPU consumed on client machine.

Client could be desktop/tab/mobile devicea